# Methods for checking for a valid object in Objective C?

Tags: objective-c

For an instance of myObject, is there a difference between

> if (myObject == nil)

and

> if (myObject)

My assumption is that if myObject hasn't been allocated and initialized, it will be nil and the two are synonymous.

UPDATE: I'm sorry, I mis-worded my question but I think you answered what I was really asking. Let me clarify:

I have two tableViews, each with its own viewController, `tblVC1` and `tblVC2`. For a user tap on a table row, the viewController configures a popver contentViewController, `contentVC`, which has tblVC1 and tblVC2 properties. So if the user tap is handled by `tblVC1`, it sets `contentVC.tblVC1 = self`, and the `tblVC2` property is not initialized.

When I need to call back to the launching viewController I have been checking for which viewController to call like this:

```
if (tblVC1) { 
    [tlbVC1 callTheMethod]; 
} else {
    [tlbVC2 callTheMethod];
}
```

So I should have asked: is `if (tblVC1)` the same as `if (tblVC1 != nil)`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`if(myObject)` checks if myObject points to an memory area != 0x0 and `if(myObject == nil)` checks if myObject points to 0x0.
Oh, and myObject won't be NULL by default, but only if it is an ivar of an ObjC class, otherwise it will point to a random memory chunk.

*(Disclaimer: Requesting a new memory page on iOS and Mac OS X will result in a clean memory page which means that myObject would be NULL in this case. But I wouldn't rely on this)*

Comment: Thanks for your reply, it helped me understand what I'm really asking. I have updated my post to clarify my question.

Comment: Yes, if(tblVC1) evaluates in this case to the same as if(tblVC1 != nil).

By the way, sending a message to NULL in objc-c is detected by the runtime and won't do anything bad (although you should check the pointers always!). You might also want to check if tlbVC2 points to something, just to be sure that also the alloc operation didn't failed.

Comment: Thanks for returning. Great answer (although I don't know what you mean about always checking the pointers).

Comment: No problem, you are welcome.
What I meant with "always check your pointers" was, that you just check for tblVC1 but never for tlbVC2 although you use both.

Answer (score 2):

Correct.  A detailed discussion of `nil` and default values is available on [Cocoa with Love](http://cocoawithlove.com/2008/06/doing-things-in-cocoa-with.html).

**Edit:** JustSid is right to point out that this is only guaranteed of instance variables.